# How to convert from '%Y:%m:%d' to date in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm using the time module and the strptime() function however it's erroring and I'm pretty sure I have the format right.

```
ds = '2014:10:9'
d = time.strptime('%Y:%m:%d', ds)
```

I get this exception:

ValueError: time data '%Y:%m:%d' does not match format '2014:10:9'

From reading the docs on strptime(), I have the right pattern, what am I missing?

Comment: `%d` - zero-padded day. you're not providing a zero-padded day, which would've been `09`.

Comment: Is there a way to use this function without zero padding days and months?

Answer (score 2):

Wrong. Use:

```
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(ds, '%Y:%m:%d')
```

Mind the order of arguments.
@Marc B : Strptime is able to parse non-padded values.

Comment: you could call `.date()` method to get `date` object from `datetime` instance.